# Angular routing does not work properly for modules

Tags: angular, typescript, url-routing, angular-routing

I am creating a management system that has multiple modules present in it

The entry point for the application is **login-module**
On successful login, it redirects the user to **main-module**
And from **main-module** user can navigate to other like inventory,customers etc.

but on changing the route from `http://localhost:4200/dashboard` to `http://localhost:4200/customers` the module **customers** does not load but it works perfectly when I route to `http://localhost:4200/customers/cutomers`

```
                                           AppModule
                                           /       \
                                          /         \
                                 login-module  -->  main-module
                                                      /      \
                                                     /        \
                                        dashboard-module      customers-module
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

Following are the relevant codes:

1. **app-component.html**

   `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
2. **app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/AuthGuard/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
 {
   path: "",
   redirectTo: '/dashboard',
   pathMatch: "full"
 },
 {
   path: "dashboard",
   loadChildren: () => import('./modules/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)
 },
 {
   path: "customers",
   loadChildren: () => import('./modules/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)
 },
 {
   path: 'login',
   loadChildren: () => import('./modules/login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule),
 },

];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

3. **main-routing.module.ts**

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/guards/AuthGuard/auth.guard';
import { MainComponent } from './components/main/main.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: MainComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('../dashboard/dashboard.module').then(m => m.DashboardModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'customers',
    component: MainComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('../customers/customers.module').then(m => m.CustomersModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MainRoutingModule { }
```

4. main.component.html

```
<div class="wrapper default-theme" [ngClass]="getClasses()">
    <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    <main>
      <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
      <div class="pages container-fluid pt-4 pb-4 pl-4 pr-4">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        <hr>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay" (click)="toggleSidebar()"></div>
    </main>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:4200/customers/**cutomers**

You have misspelled 'customers' here

Comment: yeah it was misspelled here only.Thanks anyways